# HttpWebRequest in windows 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

I just got a task to integrate my application with payment gateway. So to do this task, i have  created one sample app on windows console that connects with payment gateway and returns me response. it works fine...i am using HttpWebRequest client.

So,When I add same files in Windows 8.1 store app project, it doesn't work . It gives me loads of errors (Which works fine on console app). I don't understand why.

**I have same environment for both Apps.**

1. VS 2013
2. Windows 8.1

**Here is code code snippet**

```
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request); 
httpRequest.Method = "POST";    
httpRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length; // **this lines gives me error(like httpRequest doesnt have ContentLength property)**
httpRequest.ContentType = contentType;
httpRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;  // **same error**
using (Stream dataStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use HttpClient instead as shown here

[HttpClient for Windows Store Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761504.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Like dellywheel said: Use HttpClient combined with the Handler and HttpRequestMessage.

This is an Example of my CalDAV Code. I just changed it from PROPFIND to POST, but it still shows you how to add Content (Body), use different Headers and so on.

```
    ...
        try {
            HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            httpClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            httpClientHandler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(caldavuserTB.Text, caldavpasswordTB.Text);

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
            httpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;

            propfindMethod = new HttpMethod("POST");

            propfindHttpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(propfindMethod, webURLAsURI);

            propfindHttpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/xml; charset=utf-8");
            propfindHttpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent("<d:propfind xmlns:d=\"DAV:\" xmlns:cs=\"http://calendarserver.org/ns/\"><d:prop><d:displayname /><cs:getctag /></d:prop></d:propfind>");


            propfindHttpResponseMesage = await httpClient.SendAsync(propfindHttpRequestMessage);
        }
    ...
```